# Running Ninject 3 on medium trust level

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, medium-trust

I've an ASP.NET MVC3 application with Ninject 3. The Ninject 3 was installed using NuGet, and now I'm trying to publish this application on a host that uses medium trust level.

So after I searched on google a little I found an build on the Ninject GoogleCode project website an specific version for medium trust environments, so I downloaded and changed the references on my project, and after I published it I still get the same error.

I already changed the way that I create my kernel and I'm using:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel(new NinjectSettings { UseReflectionBasedInjection = true });
```

And I still get the error.

So anyone already faced this issue and solved it?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Open this file:  MyProjectName\Properties\ **AssemblyInfo.cs**
and then add this line

**[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]**

In the Global.asax :

```
     INinjectSettings settings = new NinjectSettings
        {
            UseReflectionBasedInjection = true,    // disable code generation for partial trust
            InjectNonPublic = false,               // disable private reflection for partial trust
            InjectParentPrivateProperties = false, // reduce magic
            LoadExtensions = false                 // reduce magic
        };

        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(settings);
```

Comment: This worked for me whenever I didn't add the AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers attribute. I am using GoDaddy shared hosting.