# Where can I download Ninject with Medium Trust for ASP .NET 4.5

Tags: ninject, medium-trust

My site is working good on my local. but on Godady server it is throwing **Method Access Exception :**

I found this article.
[Ninject error on deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003902/ninject-error-on-deployment)

So Now I found that Godady allows medium Trust of Ninject instead of Full trust.

So my question is where can I download medium trust Ninject for .net 4.5.

I tried to visit this link http://www.ninject.org/download.html but it doesnt have Ninject with medium trust dll.

Can anybody suggest another alternative. ??
Please help !!! ...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989300/running-ninject-3-on-medium-trust-level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a Ninject with Medium trust. But it was not the official one. Somebody updated the package. 
For anybody else who is looking for Ninject with Medium Trust for .net 4.5 can visit

https://teamcity.bbv.ch/viewLog.html?buildId=987&tab=artifacts&buildTypeId=bt7

login as Guest.

But I could not make that solution working.

So finally I switched to Unity. It works great in Medium Trust environments.